# Unhide RibbonRow

Tags: ribbon, custom-masterpage

I have three Site Collections:

- Main
- Search
- People directory

The *Search* and *People Directory* don't have the ribbon row (gray area that hold Browse and Page tabs) showing but I'd like to show them for continuity. The ribbon row does show when I edit a page.

Is there a way to unhide these? I haven't added anything that would normally hide this. It came that way by default. The master pages have been modified but nothing that was different than the main master page.

Answer (score 1):

Are they anonymous sites? If so login to get the ribbon. If not, it could be some CSS issue. Get the help of developer tool in browser (F12) and ascertain the issue

Let me know if you have any questions